# How do I align the div image to the center in an angularDart project?

Tags: css, sass, dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I am  trying to align the image to the center of the page, applied the following code but it didn't work.

```
.home-banner { 
text-align: center;
} .banner-image { 
display: inline-block; 
}
```

How can I align it to the center of the page.

app_component.html

```
<div class="home-banner">
    <div class="banner-container">
      <div class="banner-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app_component.scss

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';

$home-banner-image: 'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';

.home-banner {
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}    
.banner-image {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-image: url($home-banner-image);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `background-position: center;` on your background-image should fix it.

```css
.home-banner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.banner-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 150px; /* Added to show image */
    background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-banner">
    <div class="banner-container">
      <div class="banner-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below example to achieve the flex container to be centered to the page

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 text-align:center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box{
 width:100%;
 max-width:30%;
 border:1px solid red;
 margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
 <div class="box">
  <h1>This is the first box</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci voluptates, aut totam eaque possimus molestiae atque odio vero optio porro magni, quis culpa ea. Perferendis, neque, enim. Rem, quia, quisquam.</p>
 </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The picture was already centred for the current height , but that height was small and was as big as the picture image.
When trying to give the wrapper a bigger height so it's not exactly fitting than you get the wished output.

For a really centred image you can use "height: 100vh" to get all the view height.
Hope it helps :)

```css
.home-banner {
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.banner-container {
  align-self: center;
}

.banner-image {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 150px; /* Added to show image */
    background-color: black
}
```